# Can I dual boot Windows and Ubuntu with Common (EFI & Home) partitions

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, ubuntu-gnome

Both Windows and Linux support **exfat** file format.

I want combine EFI and the Home folder/partition to access files from both operating systems.

Will this work as I expect?

Comment: The EFI (FAT32 only) partition is automagically shared, but Windows does not have a Home partition.

Comment: Linux partitions like /(root) & /home have to be Linux formats like ext4. You can also then have another partition for shared data. Most have used NTFS, but Linux is improving exFAT support. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Samsung-exFAT-Utils-Release Release notes for 20.04 mention exFAT support. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes